# Why I'm receiving an CSP frame-src error even if I'm passing rules?

Tags: http, helmet.js

I'm receiving the error:

`Refused to frame 'https://oauth.telegram.org/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src https://outh.telegram.org"`

I have set my content security policy rules correctly I believe. Why is it still blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution.

I have added `*.telegram.org` rule and it worked. I don't know why the previous rule was not accurate but anyway the second try worked.

Comment: You missed the 'a' letter in https://oAuth.telegram.org/ in `iframe-src`, but wildcard solved this.